# is there a mongoose connect error callback

Tags: javascript, mongodb, node.js, mongoose

how can i set a callback for the error handling if mongoose isn't able to connect to my DB?

i know of

```
connection.on('open', function () { ... });
```

but is there something like

```
connection.on('error', function (err) { ... });
```

?

Comment: For anyone stumbling on this question, `connection.on('error', function (err) { ... });` is now implemented in 3.X.

Answer (score 126, accepted):

When you connect you can pick up the error in the callback:

```
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/dbname', function(err) {
    if (err) throw err;
});
```

Comment: What if I want my server to continue running even if there is an error?  Everything I've tried so far throws the error and then terminates the program.

Comment: If you get an error here you probably either have a configuration error or the DB server is down... In which case you most likely can't continue the app anyway. But it's also best to restart the app when there's an unexpected error anyway - otherwise it's in an unknown state.

Comment: @evilcelery All queries in mongoose are buffered, so all of them should be executed as soon as you reconnect to db, which is fine and should not be a cause of unknown state.

Comment: This does not seem to work. I can feed it a bad uri and err always returns undefined.

Comment: The error comes from the Mongoose documentation for connect() http://mongoosejs.com/docs/connections.html, which does not specify a callback is possible.

Comment: is there a way to redirect the page and send an error message to the user?

Comment: This does not work in newer Mongoose versions (3.X). See Asta's answer for a solution that works.

Answer (score 46):

there many mongoose callback you can use,

```js
// CONNECTION EVENTS
// When successfully connected
mongoose.connection.on('connected', function () {  
  console.log('Mongoose default connection open to ' + dbURI);
}); 

// If the connection throws an error
mongoose.connection.on('error',function (err) {  
  console.log('Mongoose default connection error: ' + err);
}); 

// When the connection is disconnected
mongoose.connection.on('disconnected', function () {  
  console.log('Mongoose default connection disconnected'); 
});

// If the Node process ends, close the Mongoose connection 
process.on('SIGINT', function() {  
  mongoose.connection.close(function () { 
    console.log('Mongoose default connection disconnected through app termination'); 
    process.exit(0); 
  }); 
});
```

more on: http://theholmesoffice.com/mongoose-connection-best-practice/

Comment: the on error callback doesn't provide the error anymore. it's just a boolean value saying true.

Answer (score 22):

In case anyone happens upon this, the version of Mongoose I'm running (3.4) works as stated in the question. So the following can return an error.

```
connection.on('error', function (err) { ... });
```

Comment: even this doesn't work! the value of err is just 'true'. with no description of the actual error.

Comment: @amitavamozumder check my answer of how to use catch and try/catch methods to handle errors.

Answer (score 9):

As we can see on the mongoose documentation for [Error Handling](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/connections.html#error-handling), since the [connect()](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/connections.html#callback) method returns a Promise, the promise `catch` is the option to use with a mongoose connection.

So, to handle initial connection errors, you should use `.catch()` or `try/catch` with `async/await`.

In this way, we have two options:

**Using the `.catch()` method:**

```
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/test', { useNewUrlParser: true })
.catch(error => console.error(error));
```

**or using try/catch:**

```
try {
    await mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/test', { useNewUrlParser: true });
} catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
}
```

IMHO, I think that using `catch` is a cleaner way.

Comment: On a bad connection, I get `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ReferenceError: handleError is not defined`

Comment: @staypuftman the handleError is a generic method, it not doesn't exist at all. I updated my question to make this clear.

Comment: Got it, stupid mistake on my end. It's just a generic `catch()` - thanks for the clarification

Comment: @valdeci thanks, this was mentioned in the official mongoose doc too. Still here i am looking a solution for the same in stack overflow. And i find this one as best so far

Answer (score 2):

Late answer, but if you want to keep the server running you can use this:

```
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/dbname',function(err) {
    if (err)
        return console.error(err);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

- Handle (catch) the connect exceptions
- Handle other connection errors
- show a message when successfully connected

```
mongoose.connect(
  "mongodb://..."
).catch((e) => {
  console.log("error connecting to mongoose!");
});
mongoose.connection.on("error", (e) => {
  console.log("mongo connect error!");
});
mongoose.connection.on("connected", () => {
  console.log("connected to mongo");
});
```