# Mongoose.js how to check if connection successful?

Tags: node.js, mongoose

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [is there a mongoose connect error callback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6676499/is-there-a-mongoose-connect-error-callback)

I use mongoose.createConnection to create a connection, it works in async mode.

How to check if connection was successful and how to get error if not?

Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[is there a mongoose connect error callback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6676499/is-there-a-mongoose-connect-error-callback) has a solution, and you can do this too:

```
mongoose.connection.on('error', function (err) {
 // Do something
});
```

Source: https://github.com/LearnBoost/mongoose/blob/master/lib/connection.js

Comment: var db = mongoose.connection;
db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection error:'));
db.once('open', function (callback) {
  // yay!
});  ...... see mongoosejs documentation @  http://mongoosejs.com/docs/index.html

Comment: That's the error callback and not the success callback that OP was asking for. I think Maher's 'open' callback is the right way to go.