# Node.js server cannot connect to MongooseDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am trying to run some sample code from Addy Osmani's book "Developing Backbone.js Applications".  One exercise provides a package.json file which I used to do an `npm install` and it installed Express, Mongoose and Path.  From there I ran `node server.js` from the same dir and it gave me this error:

```
Express server listening on port 4711 in development mode

events.js:72
        throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
              ^
Error: failed to connect to [localhost:27017]
    at null.<anonymous> (C:\backbone-fundamentals\exercise-2\node_modules\mongoose\node_modules\mongodb\lib\mongodb\connection\server.js:648:74)
    ...
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:415:13)
```

I'm assuming that it's having a problem connecting to the Mongoose DB but being an amateur in Node.js, Express or Mongoose, I'm not sure where to start to debug this.  How can I check if Mongoose was installed properly? By the way, I am on Windows.

---

If you're intersted, here's the entire server.js file for Node:

```
'use strict';

// Module dependencies.
var application_root = __dirname,
    express = require( 'express' ), //Web framework
    path = require( 'path' ), //Utilities for dealing with file paths
    mongoose = require( 'mongoose' ); //MongoDB integration

//Create server
var app = express();

//Connect to database
mongoose.connect( 'mongodb://localhost/library_database' );

//Schemas
var Keywords = new mongoose.Schema({
    keyword: String
});

var Book = new mongoose.Schema({
    title: String,
    author: String,
    releaseDate: Date,
    keywords: [ Keywords ]
});

//Models
var BookModel = mongoose.model( 'Book', Book );

// Configure server
app.configure( function() {
    //parses request body and populates request.body
    app.use( express.bodyParser() );

    //checks request.body for HTTP method overrides
    app.use( express.methodOverride() );

    //perform route lookup based on url and HTTP method
    app.use( app.router );

    //Where to serve static content
    app.use( express.static( path.join( application_root, 'site') ) );

    //Show all errors in development
    app.use( express.errorHandler({ dumpExceptions: true, showStack: true }));
});

// Routes
app.get( '/api', function( request, response ) {
    response.send( 'Library API is running' );
});

//Get a list of all books
app.get( '/api/books', function( request, response ) {
    return BookModel.find( function( err, books ) {
        if( !err ) {
            return response.send( books );
        } else {
            return console.log( err );
        }
    });
});

//Get a single book by id
app.get( '/api/books/:id', function( request, response ) {
    return BookModel.findById( request.params.id, function( err, book ) {
        if( !err ) {
            return response.send( book );
        } else {
            return console.log( err );
        }
    });
});

//Insert a new book
app.post( '/api/books', function( request, response ) {
    var book = new BookModel({
        title: request.body.title,
        author: request.body.author,
        releaseDate: request.body.releaseDate,
        keywords: request.body.keywords
    });
    book.save( function( err ) {
        if( !err ) {
            return console.log( 'created' );
        } else {
            return console.log( err );
        }
    });
    return response.send( book );
});

//Update a book
app.put( '/api/books/:id', function( request, response ) {
    console.log( 'Updating book ' + request.body.title );
    return BookModel.findById( request.params.id, function( err, book ) {
        book.title = request.body.title;
        book.author = request.body.author;
        book.releaseDate = request.body.releaseDate;
        book.keywords = request.body.keywords;

        return book.save( function( err ) {
            if( !err ) {
                console.log( 'book updated' );
            } else {
                console.log( err );
            }
            return response.send( book );
        });
    });
});

//Delete a book
app.delete( '/api/books/:id', function( request, response ) {
    console.log( 'Deleting book with id: ' + request.params.id );
    return BookModel.findById( request.params.id, function( err, book ) {
        return book.remove( function( err ) {
            if( !err ) {
                console.log( 'Book removed' );
                return response.send( '' );
            } else {
                console.log( err );
            }
        });
    });
});

//Start server
var port = 4711;
app.listen( port, function() {
    console.log( 'Express server listening on port %d in %s mode', port, app.settings.env );
});
```

Comment: After `mongoose.connect....` add `mongoose.on("error", function(err) {console.log("Mongoose error:", err)});` and run the application again. The specific error should be in there, post it here (comment or edit) if you need help after that.

Comment: Hmm, is that the right syntax?  I'm getting this error now:
`mongoose.on("error", function(err) {console.log("Mongoose error:", err)});
         ^
TypeError: Object #<Mongoose> has no method 'on'`

Comment: I tried to catch the error in the callback as per this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6676499/is-there-a-mongoose-connect-error-callback and it gave me an error of `[Error: failed to connect to [localhost:27017]]` which is pretty much what we had before.

Comment: Did you install MongoDB? Mongoose requires MongoDB to be running. The error implies it's not running or configured correctly.

Comment: In a shell (terminal), run `mongo` to connect to the local database. Does that work?

Comment: @randunel: no, it doesn't work

Comment: @WiredPrairie: The instructions didn't mention to install MongoDB first, I thought it was a self-contained module.  Of course, if I need to then that would be the problem, duh!  Let me do that and get back to you guys.

Comment: (The reason I said that is that you're calling it MongooseDB, which isn't a "thing").

Comment: You don't have MongoDB installed.

Comment: It actually does say install it on page 106 (I've got the book).

Comment: @WiredPrairie: you're right.  i'm officially an idiot!! i knew it was something stupid like that.  If you wanna submit that comment as an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On page 106 of the mentioned book, [Developing Backbone.js Applications](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920025344.do), it says to install MongoDB:

> Download and install MongoDB from mongodb.org. There are detailed installation guides on the website.

So, once you do that, you shouldn't have any problem connecting to the DB when using Mongoose.

Answer (score 5):

You don't have MongoDB installed.

Check this out http://www.mongodb.org/downloads

Comment: Can't accept both, but you can accept the first correct one :P

Comment: Haha, ok we could split hairs forever.  You got 10 points for comments & upvotes, so that's the best I can do.