# Nodejs in Openshift MongoDB Error

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, openshift

This could probably be very stupid and naive question, but I have tried all my ways to find the solution, but I'm unable to solve. Hope anyone can solve my problem. Thanks in advance.

Recently, I deployed my nodejs application in Open Shift using Mongolab driver for the MongoDB. When I run the application using 'rhc app start -a nodejs', it gives me an ECONNREFUSED error in mongooose.

```
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED
    at errnoException (net.js:905:11)
    at Object.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:896:19)
```

But, when I SSH into the server, go to $OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR directory and use npm start, the app works very fine.

I connect to the mongodb by defining the URI as shown

```
mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGOLAB_URI || 'mongodb://localhost/<dbname>');
```

I defined the MONGOLAB_URI as an environmental variable in the server.

There would probably be something that I'm missing. But, please bare with this naive.

Comment: It will probably help you to find out what's happening exactly during the connect. You can pass a callback to `mongoose.connect()` to find the error: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6676499/is-there-a-mongoose-connect-error-callback

Comment: It shows me the following error :Mongoose default connection error: MongoError: connect ECONNREFUSED. The error is, I defined an env MONGOLAB_URI. When I echo it in shell, it prints the correct value, but when I console.log it, it is printing undefined value.