# mongoose connection can´t handle errors

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am building my first test API rest with Mongo and Node

I am opening a connection to the database, and it works right... but I can´t handle the error case. Despite i write a wrong URI, it makes a successful connection. Tried with promises, callbacks, and events, but nothing works:

For example:

```
const mongoose=require('mongoose');
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
const express=require('express');
const bodyParser=require('body-parser');
const portApp=1300;

const app=express();

app.listen(portApp,'localhost',()=>{
    console.log(`server works fine at ${portApp}`);


    mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/RIGHTdbname')
    .then((res)=>
    {
        console.log(`successful connection to BBDD`);
       //console.log(res);
    
    })
    .catch((error)=>{

        console.log("error"+error.message);
    });
});
```

That´s ok, it throws "successful connection to BBDD"... the problem is, when I write a wrong database name, it throws the same!

I tried to with callback too. like suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6676499/is-there-a-mongoose-connect-error-callback):

```
 mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/WRONGdbname',function(err){

    if(err)
    {
        throw err;
    }
});
```

And tried to use these events (taken from [here](http://theholmesoffice.com/mongoose-connection-best-practice/), and which I actually don´t understand, only used the .on() jquery method in the past, for event delegation tasks), but it does´t work either, because always the "connected" event fires, even if database name is wrong, again.

```
// When successfully connected
mongoose.connection.on('connected', function () {  
  console.log('Mongoose default connection opened);
}); 

// If the connection throws an error
mongoose.connection.on('error',function (err) {  
  console.log('Mongoose default connection error: ' + err);
});
```

Can someone explain me what I´´m doing wrong? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "database" in the Mongo connection string is used for authentication, and is only relevant if you pass the username and password in the URL using the `mongodb://user:pass@host:port/database` syntax.

From [the reference](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/connection-string/)

> /database Optional. The name of the database to authenticate if the connection string includes authentication credentials in the form of username:password@. If /database is not specified and the connection string includes credentials, the driver will authenticate to the admin database.